# solving partial differential equation with FDM

Tags: partial-differential-equations, math-software, finite-differences

Do you know any software that can provide a numerical solution for nonlinear partial differential equations using finite difference method ?

Comment: Due to the simplicity of using a finite difference approach (compared to other numerical techniques), most people write their own code for their particular problem at hand, so I'm not too sure if there will be many codes out there you can just 'plug and play'. One particular way nonlinear PDEs are solved using finite difference methods is using a combination of implicit and explicit (IMEX) schemes, where the linear part of the PDE is treated implicitly and the nonlinear part explicitly. You can write your own code relatively easily this way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mattos

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [FreeFem++](http://www.freefem.org/), which is an open-source software that runs on various platforms.  It provides numerical solutions to [pde](/questions/tagged/pde)s as well as their [visualization](/questions/tagged/visualization)s.

Comment: Do I need to program the equation in it or it is easy to use?

Comment: Some coding is needed, but it's quite intuitive if you know your problem.  The second question is a bit subjective.  You'll find your own answer by looking at the basic examples for beginners in the manuel.

Comment: I will give it a try, many thanks for your reply @GNUSupporter

Comment: Hello,
I think as the name implies, FreeFEM (Finite element Method) rather than finite difference,
any suggestions @GNUSupporter

Comment: Sorry to say no because I'm studying ([tag:probability-theory]).